# Execute an Installer from the Puppet Filestore

Tags: puppet

I have stored the installer for a Linux product, which I need to install with an answer file. I have the following code thus far:

```
class installpackage {
    file { 'MyInstallerFile':
            path => '/tmp/MyInstallerFile',
            ensure => present,
            owner => 'root',
            group => 'root',
            mode => '777',
            source => 'puppet:///extra_files/MyInstallerFile',
    }
    file { 'answer_file':
            path => '/tmp/answer_file',
            ensure => present,
            owner => 'root',
            group => 'root',
            mode => '777',
            source => 'puppet:///extra_file/answer_file',
    }

   exec { "install":
cwd => '/tmp',
             command => '/tmp/MyInstallerFile --answer /tmp/answer_file',
            logoutput => true,
           require => File['MyInstallerFile', 'answer_file'],
   }
}
```

However, when I attempt to run it, I get a bunch of errors:

```
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Caching catalog for puppetagent.example.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1370899438'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns: couldn't find HOME environment variable to expand path
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     while executing
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns: "file normalize ~"
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     (procedure "::InstallJammer::HomeDir" line 2)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     invoked from within
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns: "::InstallJammer::HomeDir"
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     (procedure "::InstallJammer::CommonInit" line 183)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     invoked from within
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns: "::InstallJammer::CommonInit"
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     (procedure "::InstallJammer::InitInstall" line 19)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     invoked from within
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns: "::InstallJammer::InitInstall"
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns:     (file "/installkitvfs/main.tcl" line 71313)
Error: /tmp/MyInstallerFile --answer /tmp/answer_file returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Installpackage/Exec[install]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: MyInstallerFile --answer /tmp/answer_file returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Notice: Finished catalog run in 5.31 seconds
```

What about I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the way the machines were imaged, and one solution to fix the Exec issues was to add "sudo" in front of the command. Of course, this is only limited to Linux environments.

The other solution, and probably a better idea is to create Debian packages of installers that you need. This simplifies management, and rolling out new versions rather than going through uninstall routines.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Puppet runs as `root` user.

I think your `$HOME` environment variable is not set by root.

As a test, you may `su` to `root`, and `echo $HOME` to find out if that is the case.

Comment: I tried that, $HOME is set to /root. So I am not sure why Puppet isn't picking up the $HOME variable. Is there a way to manually specify it?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the $HOME variable on the command line:

```
exec { "install":
    ...
    command => 'HOME=/path/to/somewhere /tmp/MyInstallerFile --answer /tmp/answer_file',
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta do something like this.

```
   $path => $::path,   
   $cwd  => '/location/of/your/installer'
```

$::path is a reference to the default environment variables.You can set additional path in an array like this.

```
    $path => [$::path,'/additional/path/to/other/directory'],
    $cwd  => '/location/of/your/installer',
```